# "incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')" error while installing numpy on M1 Mac with pip3 on Python Version 3.10

Tags: numpy, pip, apple-m1, python-3.10

I was trying to install numpy version 1.22.3 on a M1 Macbook with pip3, and pip3 says the package is present, but when I try to import the module, an error gets thrown at me that says
`Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for`

`many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was`

`installed.`
The full text of the error is:
`dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-`

`310-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpy`

`thon-310-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/usr/lib/_multiarray_umath.cpython-310-da`

`rwin.so' (no such file)`

I followed the link to the [troubleshooting documentation](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html) provided, and none of the solutions worked.
I've tried reinstalling both pip3 and Python, and that didn't work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like the python interprerer would be x86_64 and not arm64 version, how did you install it?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I installed it off of the [Python Website's MacOS downloads page](https://www.python.org/downloads/macos/)

Comment: Got the same issue but with `black` package installed using pip (python 3.10). Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 5):

I was able to fix this issue by uninstalling and reinstalling numpy in my virtual environment.

Comment: Did you use pip3 or pip to install numpy?

Comment: Same here, I created a new virtual env and installed my code dependencies, and it was fixed.

Answer (score 4):

If none of above worked for you try this way of install numpy after remove it
`pip uninstall numpy`

### arm64 installtion

`arch -arm64 pip install numpy`

### x86_64 installtion

`arch -x86_64 pip install numpy`

or you can keep an alise for that in your bash config file:

```bash
alias pip86='arch -x86_64 pip install'
alias pip_arm='arch -arm64 pip install'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. What worked for me was to downgrade the python version from 3.10 to 3.8 and then reinstall numpy.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, what worked for me was, deleting my `.venv` folder in my python project directory, and remaking the poetry environment

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).